# In a GWT DataGrid, how do I get the row background color (which alternates based on even/odd) to style a <div> within a <td>?

Tags: css, gwt, datagrid, ellipsis

I have a DataGrid and I needed one of the columns to be limited to a max of 3 lines and then truncate overflown text and show an ellipsis to indicate that the text had been truncated (the user can hover over the cell to get a PopupPanel with the full content).

We support Chrome and IE, so unfortunately the following webkit solution is not sufficient as it only works on Chrome.

```
.chrome-overflow-ellipsis {
    display: -webkit-box;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    max-height: 3.6em;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I used the guide [here](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/) for my solution:

```
/* styles for '...' */ 
.cell-overflow-ellipsis {
  /* hide text if it more than N lines  */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* for set '...' in absolute position */
  position: relative; 
  /* use this value to count block height */
  line-height: 1.2em;
  /* max-height = line-height (1.2) * lines max number (3) */
  max-height: 3.6em; 
  /* fix problem when last visible word doesn't adjoin right side  */
  text-align: justify;  
  /* place for '...' */
  /* margin-right: -1em; */
  padding-right: 1em;
}

/* create the ... */
.cell-overflow-ellipsis:before {
  /* points in the end */
  content: '...';
  /* absolute position */
  position: absolute;
  /* set position to right bottom corner of block */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

/* hide ... if we have text, which is less than or equal to max lines */
.cell-overflow-ellipsis:after {
  /* points in the end */
  content: '';
  /* absolute position */
  position: absolute;
  /* set position to right bottom corner of text */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* set width and height */
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  /* bg color = bg color under block */
  background: inherit;
}
```

The css style needs to be applied to a `div` element within a `td` because otherwise table cell elements will take up the minimum height required by the content, rather than a maximum of n that you set.

Here's how I made my DataGrid column:

```
Column<MyObject, SafeHtml> column = new Column<MyObject, SafeHtml>(new SafeHtmlCell()) {
        @Override
        public SafeHtml getValue(MyObject object) {
            SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
            String value = object.data== null? "" : object.data;
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div class=\"cell-overflow-ellipsis\">").appendEscaped(value).appendHtmlConstant("</div>");
            return sb.toSafeHtml();
        }
    };
```

The guide had the background color in `.cell-overflow-ellipsis:after` as `white`. I used `inherit` because of the default DataGrid style which switches the background color based on whether it is an even or odd row (`.dataGridEvenRow` and `.dataGridOddRow`).

While the background color of the ellipsis will match the cell, this causes the ellipsis to always be visible instead of hiding when the content is less than or equal to 3 lines. If I set an explicit background color then the ellipsis will hide if the full content fits within 3 lines, but then some of the cells will have a small box (hidden ellipsis) with the wrong background color. We want to keep the alternating row colors.

I wanted to do something like

```
.dataGridEvenRow .cell-overflow-ellipsis:after {...}
.dataGridOddRow .cell-overflow-ellipsis:after {...}
```

Except I'm pretty sure .dataGridEvenRow gets obfuscated and I don't think there's a way to represent that descendant or pseudo-element selector in a DataGrid.Resources extension. Also, the `.cell-overflow-ellipsis` is defined in the module.css in the war folder (to make it easy for me to use in `SafeHtml` without having to use `SafeHtmlTemplate`).

How do I set the `div` background color explicitly based on the cell's row background color?

Comment: It might sound silly, but can't you just use `background-color: transparent;` for the ellipsis? Or hide it using `visibility` or `display` property?

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing that. I just tried all 3, but unfortunately none of them worked. :(